# variable "module" is not defined when trying an official example code

Tags: requirejs, npm, browserify

I copied example code into my editor, saved and it does not work (surprise :) )

I had to alter it, so as it works as expected and I have absolutely no idea, why it works after i had altered it.

I followed a http://browserify.org/ tutorial.

main.js is for me

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "uniq": "../node_modules/uniq/uniq"
    }
});

define(function (require) {
    var unique = require('uniq');
    var data = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6];
    console.log(unique(data));
});
```

This is uniq.js one I altered:
http://paste2.org/5465mVUF

The original one: http://paste2.org/wY7wP6pB

The only thing I did was i wrapped all uniq.js code inside anonymous function within a **define()** wrapper

```
define(function (require, exports, module) {
    //uniq.js code here...
});
```

My questions is why? What I did do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must decide to use only one module loader: browserify or requirejs. You cannot use both.

When You want to use `browserify` then don't use `define`, `require.config`.

When You want to use `requirejs` then don't use `nodejs` packages. Use browser-specific packages from e.g. `bower`.